# HTML row of a table hide, that when showed, isn't formatted correcly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not pretty good with CSS styles, anyway i've do a button that show an hide row of a table, but when I show it, the table isn't formatted correctly

this is the button

```
<button type="button" name="bottone_modifica<?php echo $id;?>" onclick="modifica<?php echo $id;?>()">MODIF</button>
```

the javascript that change the row

```
<script>
function modifica<?php echo $id;?> () {
modificato_tr_<?php echo $id;?>.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

and the row that normally is hide

```
<tr id="modificato_tr_<?php echo $id;?>" style="display: none;">
                <form class="form" method="post" action="">
                    <th>PREMI PER</th>
                    <th><input type="submit" name="bottone_modificato<?php echo $id;?>" value="CONFERMARE"></th>
                    <th><input type="date" name="data<?php echo $id;?>" value='<?php echo $data;?>'></th>
                    <th><input type="text" name="nome<?php echo $id;?>" size="10" maxlength="<?php echo $LENGTH_NOME;?>" value="<?php echo $nome;?>"></th>
                    <th><input type="text" name="valore<?php echo $id;?>" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 46 && event.charCode <= 57' size="6" maxlength="<?php echo $LENGTH_PREZZO;?>" value="<?php echo $valore;?>"></th>
                    <th><input type="text" name="chilometri<?php echo $id;?>" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 46 && event.charCode <= 57' size="6" maxlength="<?php echo $LENGTH_CHILOMETRI;?>" value="<?php echo $chilometri;?>"></th>
                    <th><textarea name="note<?php echo $id;?>" rows="3" cols="20" maxlength="250"><?php echo $note;?></textarea></th>
                </form>
            </tr>
```

You can see the code clean of php parts and the result here: http://www.onerentsrl.it/gestione-veicolo.php?id=102

Comment: Can you show us your code as well

Comment: You should post a minimal example that shows the issue here. In developing the minimal example, you will often answer your question, or at least clarify it beyond "it doesn't work".

Comment: What table format do you desire?

Comment: if u press button modif in my site, you can see that all unhided row is formatted at same space of 1 cell of the table